# Console on windows forms application

Tags: c#, dll, console

I am trying to open the console inside a windows form application so that I can debug things later down the road with the game engine I am currently working on. Unfortunately, for some reason, I cannot get the console to open using this code:

```
private void GameWind_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllocConsole();
}
//allows the game console to be seen during execution
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Apologies on keeping my comment in, but no matter what I do, I simply cannot get this to work. I have retyped it at least 5 times trying to find a typo, I have even tried a few other methods of bringing up the console, and so far nothing works. I feel like I'm missing something but I simply cannot put my finger on it. If anyone can find what's wrong with my code, please let me know.

Comment: You've not explained the problem you're having with the code you posted. *I cannot get the console to open* is not useful, and iehter is *so far nothing works*. In what way does it *not work*? What **specifically** can we help you with here? (And, as an almost unbreakable rule, you have to declare functions **before** you use them, not after. Have you tried looking on [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.com)?)

Comment: Also, have you tried reading the [AllocConsole docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx), which explain that if the function fails (returns 0), you can use GetLastError to find out why? And that AllocConsole does not return `bool`, but a handle to a console that you then use for further interaction with that console? It may be better for you to start by seeing [Consoles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682055(v=vs.85).aspx) first.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you checking the return value from `AllocConsole` and calling `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` to see what the problem is? I wrote a series of articles on using the console API from C#. Unfortunately the articles are no longer available online, but you can download the full source code from my web site.  http://www.mischel.com/pubs/consoledotnet.zip. What you're looking for is in the files JConsole.cs and WinCon.cs. Note, the solution and project files are very old, but the code still compiles if you include it in a new solution.

Comment: How is "the console will not open" is not useful? The entire point of the code snippet is to open the console and tell it what if any bugs have occurred. It not doing what it is supposed to do is in itself a problem, is it not?

Comment: "the console will not open" is not useful because it gives us no information on which to base an answer. Tell us whether `AllocConsole` returned true or false. And if it returned false, then tell us what `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` returned.

Comment: @KenWhite: Actually, in C# you don't have to declare the function before use. The compiler is perfectly happy to compile that code as written. Just like you don't have to make a forward declaration of a method. That is, A can call B even though B is declared after A.

Comment: @JimMischel: OK. I stand corrected. Strike the sentence surrounded by parentheses from my first comment. I'll leave everything else stand. :-)

Answer (score -2):

I really don't understand what Console inside Windows Form mean.

Do you want Console windows attach on Windows Form like other controls Button, TextBox, etc.. or you just want to display it when you run application?

I have some ideas:

1. Using RichTextBox control.
2. Set project type to Console application. In this case, both Windows Form and Console will show when you run your application.
3. Write everything to Debug window instead.
4. Write everything to log file instead.

Hope it useful.